# Objects have changed outside of Terraform and subsequent "terraform apply" deletes resources without any changes in the scripts

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Here are the scripts.

1. On first "apply" the behavior is as expected.
2. On 2nd "apply" I get the "Objects have changed outside of Terraform" even though there have been no manual changes of resources.
3. Also, on 2nd "apply" the subnet gets deleted.

**---modules---**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  address_space       = var.vnet_address_space
  dns_servers         = var.dns_servers
  subnet              = []
}
```

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = var.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = var.subnet_address_space
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = var.enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies
}
```

---

```
module "vnet_gateway_dev" {
    source = "./../../az_modules/vnet"
    
    vnet_name                           = var.vnet_name
    resource_group_name                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    vnet_address_space                  = var.vnet_address_space
    dns_servers                         = var.dns_servers
    depends_on                          = [data.azurerm_resource_group.rg]    
}
```

```
module "subnet" {
  source = "./../../az_modules/subnet"
  for_each = {for subnet in var.subnet_config: subnet.subnet_name => subnet}

  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  vnet_name            = each.value.vnet_name
  subnet_name          = each.value.subnet_name
  subnet_address_space = each.value.subnet_adress_space
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = each.value.enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies
  depends_on = [module.vnet_gateway_dev]
}
```

**---input-file---**

```
resource_group_name="RG-01"
vnet_name = "VNET-DEV-01"
vnet_address_space = ["10.104.0.0/22"]
nsg_location="germanywestcentral"
dns_servers = []
subnet_config = [
  {
    vnet_name = "VNET-DEV-01"
    subnet_name = "snet-01"
    subnet_adress_space = ["10.104.0.0/28"]
    enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = null
    nsg_rules = []
  }
```

---Here is the terraform plan---

```
Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the


  # module.subnet["snet-01"].azurerm_subnet.subnet has been changed
  ~ resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
        id                                             = "/subscriptions/1111111111111111/***/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET-DEV-01/subnets/snet-01"
        name                                           = "snet-01"
      + service_endpoint_policy_ids                    = []
      + service_endpoints                              = []
        # (6 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
  # module.vnet_gateway_dev.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet has been changed
  ~ resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
        id                    = "/subscriptions/1111111111111111/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET-DEV-01"
        name                  = "VNET-DEV-01"
      ~ subnet                = [
          + {
              + address_prefix = "10.104.0.0/28"
              + id             = "/subscriptions/1111111111111111/***/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET-DEV-01/subnets/snet-01"
              + name           = "snet-01"
              + security_group = ""
            }
}


------------

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.vnet_gateway_dev.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
        id                    = "/subscriptions/1111111111111111/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET-DEV-01"
        name                  = "VNET-DEV-01"
      ~ subnet                = [
          - {
              - address_prefix = "10.104.0.0/28"
              - id             = "/subscriptions/1111111111111111/***/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET-DEV-01/subnets/snet-01"
              - name           = "snet-01"
              - security_group = ""
            },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you show plan output? What exactly causes the replacement?

Comment: @Marcin I have added the plan. I am not sure what causes the deletion. There are no manual changes in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this happens because you are **deleting those subnets** by using:

```
 subnet              = []
```

TF docs [write](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network):

> At this time you **cannot use** a Virtual Network with in-line Subnets in conjunction with any Subnet resources. Doing so will cause a conflict of Subnet configurations and will overwrite Subnet's.

So you have to decide if you want to use `subnet` in `azurerm_virtual_network` or a separate resource `azurerm_subnet`. You can't mix both at the same time.

Comment: @Morariu No problem. Glad I could help.